# Akka stream group by an ID

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'd like to know how can I use the groupby in akka streams. I have an iterator that contains (id, someData)

How can I groupBy the id, so I would get Seq(id, someData)

```
Source.fromIterator(() => { groupedIterator }).groupBy(2, _._1)
  .map(p => groupById(p))
  .async
  .mergeSubstreams
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

The problem is that the val `p` is not a sequence but a singular tuple value. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: It is a Tuple2 because you already have made a gorupBy action so your stream from that point is a tuples stream.

Comment: It seems you are wanting to do some aggregation of the groups. However, the streams opened by groupBy are open as long as the original stream is open. You can use the `fold` operator inside of the substreams to aggregate data but the final result will only be delivered when the original or the substream closes.

Comment: @jrudolph yes I want to do aggregation on the groups. I will try to use fold. Thank you